# C++ WinAPI - ListView sort

Tags: c++, listview, winapi

I'm trying to do sort in a ListView. Didn't found any complete example how to do it, only a pieces of code.
I've already created ListView, added columns and items, specified my Comp function. However my problem is that lp1 and lp2 are always 0. I've checked documentation and it says : "These are the values that were specified in the lParam member of the items' LVITEM structure when they were inserted into the list." which I do set.
Here is the code :

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"comctl32.lib")

HWND ListView;
HWND hwnd;
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpszArgument, int nCmdShow)
{
    MSG messages;
    WNDCLASSEX wincl = { 0 };

    wincl.lpszClassName = "Testtttt";
    wincl.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wincl.style = CS_DBLCLKS;
    wincl.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wincl.hIcon = 0;
    wincl.hIconSm = 0;
    wincl.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wincl.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0,0,0));// COLOR_BACKGROUND;
    wincl.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

    RegisterClassEx(&wincl);

    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,
        wincl.lpszClassName,
        "Test",
        WS_SYSMENU | WS_EX_STATICEDGE | WS_VISIBLE,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        1000,
        500,
        hwnd,
        NULL,
        GetModuleHandle(NULL),
        NULL);

    RECT rec;
    GetClientRect(hwnd, &rec);
    SetWindowPos(ListView, 0, 0, 0, rec.right, rec.bottom - 23, 0);

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);

    while (GetMessage(&messages, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&messages);
        DispatchMessage(&messages);
    }
}

void AddListViewItem(char item, char *text)
{
    static int i;
    LVITEM lis;
    lis.mask = LVIF_TEXT /*| LVIF_PARAM*/;
    lis.pszText = (LPSTR)(text);
    lis.iItem = i;
    lis.iSubItem = item;
    lis.lParam = i;
    if (item==1)
    i++;
    if (item == 0)
        ListView_InsertItem(ListView, &lis);
    else
        SendMessage(ListView, LVM_SETITEM, 0, (LPARAM)&lis);
}

int CALLBACK myCompFunc(LPARAM lp1, LPARAM lp2, LPARAM sortParam)
{
    bool isAsc = (sortParam > 0);
    int column = abs(sortParam) - 1;

    char tmp[128];
    sprintf_s(tmp,sizeof tmp, "%d %d %d", lp1, lp2, column);
    MessageBox(0, (LPCSTR)tmp, "myCompFunc", MB_OK);
    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (message == WM_NOTIFY)
    {
        LPNMHDR lpnmh = (LPNMHDR)lParam;
        if (lpnmh->idFrom == 8553)
        if (lpnmh->code == LVN_COLUMNCLICK)
        {
            NMLISTVIEW*    pListView = (NMLISTVIEW*)lParam;
            ListView_SortItems(ListView, myCompFunc, pListView->iSubItem);
        }
    }
    else if (message == WM_CREATE)
    {
        ListView = CreateWindow(WC_LISTVIEW, (LPCSTR)L"", (WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | LVS_REPORT), 0, 0, 900, 500, hwnd, (HMENU)8553, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
        SendMessage(ListView, LVM_SETEXTENDEDLISTVIEWSTYLE, 0, LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT); // Set style

        LVCOLUMN listColumn = { 0 };
        listColumn.mask = LVCF_FMT | LVCF_WIDTH | LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_SUBITEM;
        listColumn.pszText = "Column1";
        listColumn.cx = 150;
        listColumn.fmt = LVCFMT_LEFT;
        ListView_InsertColumn(ListView, 0, &listColumn);
        listColumn.pszText = "Column2";
        listColumn.cx = 150;
        listColumn.iSubItem = 1;
        ListView_InsertColumn(ListView, 1, &listColumn);

        {
            AddListViewItem(0, "a");
            AddListViewItem(1, "a 1");

            AddListViewItem(0, "b");
            AddListViewItem(1, "b 1");

            AddListViewItem(0, "c");
            AddListViewItem(1, "c 1");
        }
    }
    else if (message == WM_DESTROY)
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
    }
    else
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: assuming that you're trying to make the listview sort things, you would do better to just sort your data yourself, at least for bulk insertions

Comment: In original project there is about 15 columns. Of course I could clear whole ListView and just insert again, but even now inserting cca. 20000 items * 15 columns can take half a minute! Would like to see the performance with a case of Comparison function, and it really bothers me why lParams are always zero.

Comment: Solved this issue. My LVIF_PARAM was commented for some reason ...